# Prometheus unauthorized access to Azure Kubernetes API

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I'm trying to setup a Prometheus monitoring on a dedicated Linux VM to get Kubernetes cluster metrics.

Whatever I try, I'm always blocked with the nice message Unauthorized...

This is my scrape config for pods:

```
- job_name: 'Kubernetes'
scheme: https
tls_config:
  insecure_skip_verify: true
bearer_token: %VeryLongLine%
kubernetes_sd_configs:
- api_server: https://%ClusterName%.hcp.westeurope.azmk8s.io
  tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true
  role: node
  namespaces:
    names: [default]
```

The token is the correct one because a Invoke-WebRequest from PowerShell works just fine.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
- job_name: 'Kubernetes'
  scheme: https
  tls_config:
   insecure_skip_verify: true
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - api_server: https://%ClusterName%.hcp.westeurope.azmk8s.io
    bearer_token: %VeryLongLine%
    role: node
    namespaces:
      names: [default]
```

Bearer token at the right place, so in the kubernetes config and not the job

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the CA for your service account:

```
- job_name: 'Kubernetes'
  scheme: https
  tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true
    ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
  bearer_token: %VeryLongLine%
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - api_server: https://%ClusterName%.hcp.westeurope.azmk8s.io
    role: node
    namespaces:
      names: [default]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: at the end the bearer_token line wasn't at the correct place... but now I'm facing an issue with pods, I keep getting   Get https://10.100.52.68:443/metrics: dial tcp 10.100.52.68:443: connect: connection refused which is a pod. I can't wget the url in question from my vm but I can ping the pod (added a network card into pod's network)